# block a folder, so that a wine installation/update does not change the content of the folder

Tags: debian, directory, fonts, wine

I use a debian based linux distribution.
My file system is ext4.
I also have installed wine.
I have made changes in the folder "/opt/wine-staging/share/wine/fonts/".
What changes did I made? I have deleted some of the files in this folder. And I have replaced some of the files in this folder.

What do I want:
I want to be able to install or update wine in a way, that the changes I have manually made in "/opt/wine-staging/share/wine/fonts/" will not be overwritten by the installation or update.

Is there a way, to get this?

What I have already tried out:
I tried to use this command to get what I want:

```
$ sudo chattr -R +i fonts
```

Result:
When I then install wine I get the following message and the installation breaks down:

```
Previously unselected package wine-staging is selected.
Preparation for unpacking .../91-wine-staging_5.6-1mx19+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking of wine-staging (5.6-1mx19+1) ...
dpkg: Error while editing the archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-uAdnvm/91-wine-staging_5.6-1mx19+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
"/opt/wine-staging/share/wine/fonts/arial.ttf.dpkg-new" could not be created (while processing "./opt/wine-staging/share/wine/fonts/arial.ttf"): The operation is not allowed
dpkg-deb: Error: "insert" subprocess was killed by signal (broken pipe)
Previously unselected package winehq-staging is selected.
Preparation for unpacking .../92-winehq-staging_5.6-1mx19+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking of winehq-staging (5.6-1mx19+1) ...
Errors occured while editing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-uAdnvm/91-wine-staging_5.6-1mx19+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
My Account
```

Is there any other solution to get what I want?
Is there even a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/60winefiles`:

```
path-exclude=/opt/wine-staging/share/wine/fonts/*
```

Comment: This will affect all the files in `/opt/wine-staging/share/wine/fonts/`, not just the changes the OP made.

Comment: Then the op write as many lines as many files he'd changed.